# How the jvm process can still be alive after crash in native code (EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) )?

Tags: java, crash, jvm, java-native-interface, jogl

I have a java application which uses JOGL panels to execute some openGL commands (they depend on some JNI dynamic libraries).
Sometimes my application crashes and the jvm prompts me the crash report indicating that the crash is caused by an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) in native code, but the process is often still alive, while I expect it to be halted by the OS (Windows 7 in my case).
How is it possible?
Is there a way to recognize this situation?

Comment: Does the error box look like a windows crash reporter ?

Comment: It can be alive since a Java VM can use Structured Exception Handling, this means that even a C/C++ null pointer dereference can be trapped and cause it to be converted to a Java NullPointerException if there is JNI in use.  Also the hs_err_pid*.log files JVMs generate require the program not to crash in order to continue to run the write out that file.  Again all part of SEH on Windows (aka SIGSEGV handler on Unix systems).  There are VM command line options you can pass to disable this and make it always crash (can help when debugging JNI).

Comment: @DarrylMiles I looked for command line options to make the jvm always crash, but I couldn't find them: do you have any hint?

Comment: -Xcheck:jni ?  -Xrs (maybe IBM JVM specific) ?

Comment: Ciao Matteo, this is the symptom of a serious error somewhere